# How to draw the rectangle on the top level

Tags: python, wxpython

I want to to draw a rectangle on the top of a bitmap by mouse move. But the rectangle is render under the bitmap. Following is my code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys, os
import wx
import wx.lib.scrolledpanel as scrolled

class ImgPanel(scrolled.ScrolledPanel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(ImgPanel, self).__init__(parent, 
                                       style = wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)

        self.bitmap=wx.StaticBitmap(parent=self)
        image = wx.Bitmap('image.jpg')
        self.bitmap.SetBitmap(image)

        self.imgSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)        
        self.imgSizer.Add(self.bitmap, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(self.imgSizer)

        self.SetAutoLayout(1)
        self.SetupScrolling()    
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)
        self.bitmap.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.OnMove)
        self.bitmap.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.OnLeftDown)
        self.bitmap.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP, self.OnLeftUp)
        self.IsRectReady = False
        self.newRectPara=[0,0,0,0]


    def OnMove(self,evt):
        if True == self.IsRectReady:
            self.newRectPara[2]=evt.GetPosition()[0]-self.newRectPara[0]+1
            self.newRectPara[3]=evt.GetPosition()[1]-self.newRectPara[1]+1
            self.Refresh()

    def OnLeftDown(self, evt):
        self.IsRectReady=True
        self.newRectPara[0]=evt.GetPosition()[0]
        self.newRectPara[1]=evt.GetPosition()[1]


    def OnLeftUp(self, evt):
        self.IsRectReady=False

    def OnPaint(self, evt):        
        dc=wx.PaintDC(self)
        dc.Clear()
        if self.IsRectReady:
            dc.DrawRectangle(self.newRectPara[0], self.newRectPara[1],
                             self.newRectPara[2], self.newRectPara[3])

class  WinFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title, width, height):
        super(WinFrame, self).__init__(parent, 
                                       title=title,
                                       size=(width, height))

        self.imgPanel = ImgPanel(self)
        self.frameSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)        
        self.frameSizer.Add(self.imgPanel, 1, wx.EXPAND)        
        self.SetAutoLayout(True)
        self.SetSizer(self.frameSizer)
        self.Layout()      

        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)        


class MyApp(wx.App):
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__(0)

        self.width = width
        self.height = height

    def createFrame(self):
        self.frame = WinFrame(None, "test", self.width, self.height)
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)    

def main():
    app = MyApp(640, 480)
    app.createFrame()
    app.MainLoop()

if "__main__" == __name__ :
    main()
```

Comment: In other frameworks I've always used a container which can hold an image as well as a drawn rectangle (e. g. a canvas).  Can't you use such a thing?  AFAICS that `DC` thing is probably always below the image, so your approach won't work.

Comment: I consider to use `floatcanvas` first. But I can't find good tutorials. I use `staticbitmap` widget into scrolled panel to generate scrolled bar. I don't know some other way to render a big image while can generate scrolled bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the wx.StaticBitmap is a separate (child) window it will always be on top of its parent, the ImgPanel.  So in other words, any drawing done on the ImgPanel will always be bhind or underneath the bitmap widget.  If you want the image and your drawing to be combined then instead of using the wx.StaticBitmap you should add drawing the bitmap to your EVT_PAINT handler.

Comment: Did you mean I should use `DC.DrawBitmap` instead of `StaticBitmap` widget. I have tried that method. But if the image is bigger than the panel. It can't generate a scrolled bar

Comment: Use wx.ScrolledWindow, set the virtual size of the window to be large enough to display all of the image, and set the scroll rate to set the increments that the scrollbars will use.

Comment: I have two panel in the frame. One panel is for the image. So I should use one panel and one scrolled window in one frame. Right?